# Pagination with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I want to paginate 7 results, this is pagination tag I created to do that:

```
<pagination 
            ng-model="currentPage"
            total-items="array.length"
            max-size="maxSize"
            boundary-links="true">
        </pagination>
```

And controller code:

```
exampleApp.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.currentPage = 1; // 2 - $watch triggers twice
    $scope.numPerPage = 2;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;

    array = $.map(array, function(value, index) {
        return [value];
    });
    $scope.array = array;
    $scope.filteredArray = [];

    $scope.order = function(field) {
      $scope.reverse = ($scope.field === field) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
      $scope.field = field;
    };
    $scope.field = 'id';
    $scope.reverse = false;

    $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
        , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
        alert(begin + " " + end);
        $scope.filteredArray = $scope.array.slice(begin, end);
    });
}]);
```

The problem is that I don't know how angular counts the number of pages. In this configuration I get only 1 page, I can't get the correct value of 4 pages.

Also, $watch triggers twice when I manually set currentPage to 2 or more. First time with correct begin/end values, second with previous ones, so it doesn't paginate.

How can I solve this?

EDIT:

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ui.bootstrap']).config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
});

exampleApp.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.numPerPage = 2;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;

    array = $.map(array, function(value, index) {
        return [value];
    });
    $scope.array = array;
    $scope.filteredCreations = [];

    $scope.order = function(field) {
      $scope.reverse = ($scope.field === field) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
      $scope.field = field;
    };
    $scope.field = 'id';
    $scope.reverse = false;

    $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
        , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

        $scope.filteredArray = $scope.array.slice(begin, end);
    });
}]);
```

Partial view:

```
<div ng-controller="CreationController">
<div class="row" style="text-align: right; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <pagination 
            ng-model="currentPage"
            total-items="array.length"
            max-size="maxSize"
            boundary-links="true">
        </pagination>
    </div>
<div class="foobar accordion" ng-repeat="arr in filteredArray | orderBy : field : reverse">
[[arr.id]]
[[arr.name]]
</div>
```

Comment: Please include a full example including the directive

Comment: Sure, I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="foobar accordion" ng-repeat="arr in filteredArray | orderBy : field : reverse|itemsPerPage:7">
```

Try to add **itemsPerPage:7** in your ng-repeat collection.